# Cannot Launch KDiff3 External Merge Tool from Sourcetree

Tags: merge, atlassian-sourcetree, kdiff3

I am having an issue with source tree.
I have a conflict in my merge, and tried to run kdiff3.
for some reason it is not work with the new sourcetree.

this is my source tree config
[image]

this is what display on screen after I try to run external merge tool

[image]

I found someone wrote this that helped him, but I did not understand what to do?
can someone explains step by step what is the solution?
My source tree version is 3.4.2

```
After trying various external diff tools, this is what finally worked for me in the release of Source Tree I downloaded today (9/9/2020).   Too bad this is not documented anywhere?  You need a HOME environment variable for the Windows source tree client to work with external diff and external merge tools.
```

Comment: Your comment _"After trying various external diff tools..."_ should really be added as a separate answer instead of as a comment in the question (which is definitely easy to miss!)

Comment: For some reason it works only if kdiff3 is declared both as "External diff tool" and "Merge tool"